# Putting date as xml file name

Tags: android, xml

I want to create an xml file and put the date as name

//I create here a new xmlfile called Date.xml

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String Date= df.format(c.getTime());
File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/"+Date+".xml");

try {
Log.v("CreateXML", "create file:" + newxmlfile.createNewFile());
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
}
FileOutputStream fileos = null;
try {
fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
    }
```

The Xml file is not created and i get that error

E/(12438): 19-mars-2014 05:06:19
E/IOException(12438): exception in createNewFile() method
E/FileNotFoundException(12438): can't create FileOutputStream
E/Exception(12438): error occurred while creating xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Date` instead of the current filename `"new"`.

E.g.: `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/"+Date+".xml");`

Comment: That's not an answer.

Comment: I already tried what you said @D.R. but the xml file can't be created

Comment: Then please give us the concrete error message. Probably `:` are not allowed within file names in your file system. Adjust your date format accordingly.

Comment: As I said, remove the `:` from the date format. Most probably they are not allowed on your file system.